# What is this angiosperm from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is this species of angiosperm? It's got succulent stems and leaves that do not produce latex. Photographed in spring.

[image: Flower from Morocco]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a species of Carpobrotus, probably Carpobrotus edulis. However, after looking online, several of the Carpobrotus species look very similar. It is an invasive species in the Mediterranean region. See the Wikipedia link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpobrotus#Species